# How to add element below textbox by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textbox, element

i have `html` code

```
  <div class="col-sm-10 labelRequired">
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dataSiswaVM.student_full_name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control mandatory" } })

  </div>
```

and Javascript code

```
$(".mandatory").blur(function () {
    var _value = $(this).val();
    if (_value == "" || _value == null) {
        $(".labelRequired").each(function (index, value) {
            $(this).html("<label class='newVal-message-red'>Fill the field</label>");
        });
    }
});
```

The scenario is, when the cursor is up from textbox but the textbox still empty, `javascript` will add element label inside div class `labelRequired`.
So, text "Fill The Field" will be shown up below textbox.

But, the problem is, text "Fill The Field" replace textbox insted.
The text "Fill The Field" is appear, and the textbox is gone.

How should i do for the right scenario that i want.
Thank you.

Comment: use `.append()` instead of `.html()` which replaces the element

Comment: Lols, i don't think of that. Thank you Bro.